# JavaScript, passing User ID via JSON is a security risk?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm making a little web application using PHP and JavaScript and I've come to a point where I'm not sure how to 'hide' the user's ID. Let me illustrate...

I have a page which uses a lot of JavaScript (it's based around the Google Maps API). When the user has done all their stuff, I make a single JavaScript object containing all the stuff I want to write to the database (locations from the map essentially). So I want to pass this object to another script using AJAX, which is of course very trivial using JQuery (which I am).

Herein lies the problem, along with the JavaScript object I'm going to need to pass the User's ID so the script it passes to knows which user to associate the values in the object with. I feel that if I pass it with JavaScript then somebody could easily come along start passing a false User ID and adding lots of stuff to the db that associates itself with a different user.

I could pass the User ID with PHP but then how do I give the JavaScript object to PHP?

Can anybody offer any advice on how I can pass the map data with JavaScript but somehow not expose the User ID detail?

Comment: Do the users log on to your app or is it based on anonymous visits?

Comment: By the sounds of it, you have set something on the client side to hold the userId, why not put it in the users session instead, then you don't need to pass the id?

Comment: Doesn't PHP have any abstractions for this? The most commonly used method is to not pass any user information except when logging on, at which time you will get a cookie from the server (which contains only nonsense) that will let the server identify you. If you don't send this cookie to the server, you're not identified. Judging by the other comments and answers, it sounds like this is built-into PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security risk: anybody could try to edit the user id and overwrite the data from other users.
You should consider using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), which will let you identify the user on the server: when the server gets a request, you know who it is coming from and can act accordindly.

Answer (score 1):

Like said @John Richie, if it is not anonymous (that I assume no, if users have ids) you should use a session_id and pass it instead of the id through JS. Once received, check the session_id, retrieve user_id and do your stuff.

Comment: Very helpful, cheers :) (Would have accepted had @John Richie not got there first!)